# UIView Top Point is Lower Then Expected

Tags: layout, swiftui, vstack

[image]

[image]

I have a format problem. How I want is the 2nd picture but for some reason, my view starts a little bit lower. You can see the gap between the pictures. I want to solve this problem without offset. Might be because of .navigationBarHidden(true) but I do not want navigation bar.

I added NavigationView to my code because I have a button down-right to add a new task.

Plus for some reason, this button is not clickable. Would be good if you give a hand to that problem.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskListView: View {
@State private(set) var data = ""
@State var isSettings: Bool = false
@State var isSaved: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.9450980392, blue: 0.9882352941, alpha: 1)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                TopBar()
                HStack {
                    CustomTextField(data: $data, tFtext: "Find task", tFImage: "magnifyingglass")
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isSettings.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4274509804, green: 0.2196078431, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
                            Image("buttonImage")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    })
                }
                CustomSegmentedView()
                ZStack {
                    TaskFrameView()
                    Button( action: {
                        self.isSaved.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.7137254902, blue: 0.2196078431, alpha: 1)))
                            Text("+")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.title)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .offset(x: 150, y: 220)
                    })
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: NewTaskView(),
                        isActive: $isSaved,
                        label: {
                            Text("")
                        })
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
      .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
 }

struct TopBar: View {
  var body: some View {
      HStack {
         Image("avatar")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            DateView()
                .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay", size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
            Text("Hi, Random")
                .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay", size: 20))
        }
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is navigation view bar. The `navigationBarHidden` modifier should be *inside* `NavigationView`, like

```
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(true) // << here !!
    Spacer()
} // end of NavigationView
```

Comment: yes that's it. Do you have any idea for the button though?

Comment: The `.offset(x: 150, y: 220)` does not move the view it changes the place where it is drawn on screen, so your real button is located not in the place where you see it and try to tap. Just don't use offset for buttons, ever, it is always origin of confuse.